# Increment a block of dates by day

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to increment a block of dates and times by selecting the block and then dragging down, however the days just duplicate. The block is a days worth of meeting times

This is my original data:

[image]

And when I drag down I get this:

[image]

What I actually want is for the next block to be the 18th, and then the next block to be the 19th etc... How would I go about achieving that?

Comment: In the cell below just put =A2+1 if A2 is your start cell for the date, then drag this formula down

Comment: I want the block of days to increment in blocks. The first picture is 10 rows of one day, the 17th. I would like the next 10 rows to be the 18th, the next 10 the 19th etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `Mod()` as one option.

Assuming that `A1` is a header, and `A2` has a date manually typed in, put this in `A3` and drag down:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),10)=2,A2+1,A2)
```

[image]